# how to overwrite QApplication::exec()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, overwrite, mainloop

in SDL,SFML you need to implement your own main loop.However in Qt it is predefined as `QApplication::exec()` . But I want to declare my own main loop in Qt for some other APIs t works. I tried `QTimer` which works great but I don't want it for some reason . **what is minimal code I require** to overwrite `QApplication::exec()`.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Mixing Qt and SDL,SFML is a strange requirement. Why?

Comment: @selbie I am trying to integrate Qt main loop with my SDL2 main loop.

Comment: @MarekR I am trying to go down deep in rabbit hole

Comment: What about inheriting from _QApplication_ and reimplementing _exec()_?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `QTimer`?

Comment: @scopchanov yes I am asking for that.How can I do that ? what is minimal code for that ?

Comment: @user10168069, exactly the way one inherits from any class in C++: `class myApplication : public QApplication { ... int exec() override; ... };`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607825/how-to-override-qapplicationnotify-in-qt